# roblox studio Lua - how to make it so that when a player is standing on a button

Tags: lua, roblox

I was struggling with figuring out how to make it so that when a player is standing on a button, it will give them a multiplier constantly until they stop stepping on it so that you don't have to move around and wiggle on the button.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Short = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.Short)
local config = script.Parent.Config

script.Parent.Part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid") then
        if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
            local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            if plr:FindFirstChild("Stats") and plr.Stats:FindFirstChild("Rebirth")then
                if plr.Stats.Cash.Value >= config.Cost.Value then
                    plr.Stats.Cash.Value = plr.Stats.Cash.Value - config.Cost.Value
                    plr.Stats.Multiplier.Value = plr.Stats.Multiplier.Value + config.Amount.Value * plr.Stats.Rebirth.Value
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end)
script.Parent.Part.GUI.TextLabel.Text = "$"..Short.en(config.Cost.Value).." = x"..Short.en(config.Amount.Value).." Multiplier"
```

however, this just makes it so that when the button is touched it gives a multiplier but you have to wiggle on the button and I find it annoying, does anyone know what kind of changes I can make? I'm super new to scripting so I don't fully understand it yet.

does anyone know what kind of changes I can make? I'm super new to scripting so I don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: Enable the effect on touched, and disable it on [TouchEnded](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart#TouchEnded)